# How to display and loop record from database to label one by one with timer

Tags: c#, windows

I am developing windows form project with C# where I need to display record from access database to label, but it should not show entire record at a time rather it should show record from database one at a time and so on looping one by one with timer say 5 seconds. Any kind of suggestion will be helpful and will be highly appreciable.
Below is the code I was trying but gave up:

```
   private void BindLabel()
   {
        string constring = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\LicensedDB.accdb;
        Persist Security Info=True;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=abc123";
        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constring))
        {
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT TaskDetails FROM TaskReminder ", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                using (OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);

                       //label1
                        // Please guide me, any suggestion will be higly helpful and appreciable.

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make DataTable global to form and then use timer

```
DataTable dtReminders = null;
int i = 0;
private void BindLabel()
   {
        string constring = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\LicensedDB.accdb;
        Persist Security Info=True;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=abc123";
        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constring))
        {
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT TaskDetails FROM TaskReminder ", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                using (OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                        sda.Fill(dtReminders);    
                        if(dtReminders.Rows.Count > 0)
                          timer.Start();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In timer tick event add below lines

```
if(i >= dtReminders.Rows.Count)
    i = 0;
if(dtReminders.Rows[i]["columnName"] != null)
     lblRemider.Text = dtReminders.Rows[i]["columnName"].ToString();
     i++;
```

Comment: thank you for sharing your code but it throws an error "nullreferenceexception was unhandled". What do I do now?

Comment: thank you for sharing your code but it throws an error "nullreferenceexception was unhandled". What do I do now? I have also enable timer to true and set interval to 1000.

Comment: I get error in time ticker in this line :  lblReminder.Text = dtReminders.Rows[i]["TaskName"].ToString();

Comment: Do a null check for the dtReminders here also check for last row with row count

Comment: It says object reference not set to instance of object

Comment: Have you declared DataTable at form level ?

Comment: Yes I did:  private OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
        DataTable dtReminders = null;
        int i = 0;
      
        public LabelTest()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\LicensedDB.accdb;
            Persist Security Info=True;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=abc123";
           // BindLabel();

           
        }

Comment: Have applied the changes in answer? Those conditions?

Comment: @Turing Is this working with any of the solutions provided ?

Comment: @ Krishna no bro no luck :( I have used all your code but did not work, I have also tried @ Afshin's code and method but none of it works, poor luck :(

Comment: Have you updated your code with the if conditions I kept above in answer ?